# Setup WebStorm + Node.js + nodemon + babel-node

Tags: node.js, webstorm, babeljs, nodemon, babel-node

My configuration in WebStorm looks like this:

[image: config]

and it fails with

```
[nodemon] 1.18.10
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node server.js`
[nodemon] unable to run executable: "babel-node"
[nodemon] Error
    at Bus.utils.bus.on (/Users/SOME_PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/nodemon/lib/nodemon.js:156:25)
    at Bus.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/SOME_PATH_TO_PROJECT/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:143:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:427:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

The latest `@babel/node` is installed with yarn both globally and locally (node_modules):

```sh
$ which babel-node
/usr/local/bin/babel-node
```

Also tried give absolute `babel-node` path and relative local path (targeting node_modules). No luck.

Any idea why WebStorm cannot execute the installed `babel-node`? Needless to say, it works in the terminal.

Comment: can be a `$PATH` issue. Does it work if you start WebStorm from terminal (`open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the issue of not found `babel-node` executable, I'd strongly recommend avoiding using `babel-node` to run/debug your code. I'd suggest using `-r babel-register` instead. Just create a `.babelrc` like

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

and then use a configuration like the follows to run/debug your application:

[image]

Comment: This one fails with `unable to run executable: "node"`. `node` is obviously in the $PATH, meaning that *all* executables in `--exec` cannot be resolved And if that's correct configuration in webstorm and works for you, then I am missing something more here

Comment: sure it works for me. Did you try starting webstorm from terminal (see my comment)?

Comment: yes, but no luck, with either with or without `sudo`. Global `/usr/local/bin/nodemon` also fails

Comment: hmm.. is it specific to nodemon? what is the result of running a file with  `require('child_process').exec('node somefile.js', function(error, stdout) {});` via Node.js run configuration?

Comment: Finally fixed. The issue was that my node project was in a subfolder from the Webstorm opened project. Still, I don't fully understand why because the working dir was targeting the subfolder..